# How can I use fromProviderState with path parameter in Pact?

Tags: javascript, pact

I am new to pact consumer testing. I am creating consumer pact using JavaScript. To verify with provider I need fromProvderState path parameter. I am using pactV3, here is the code

```
.given('set id', { id: 52})
        .withRequest({
          method: 'GET',
          path: fromProviderState('data/xml/${id}', 'data/xml/42'),
            headers: {
              Accept: MatchersV3.like(APP_JSON),
              'Content-Type': APP_JSON,
            },           
          })
```

I tried many example but couldn't make it work. My expectation is something like this

```
"path": {
  "dataType": "STRING",
  "expression": "data/xml/${id}",
  "type": "ProviderState"
}
```

In response json file this is what I am getting

```
"method": "GET",
 "path": "data/xml/42",
```

Can somebody please help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Why is that response json file a problem? What are you expecting it to do and why do you think you need it?

The `fromProviderState` feature only does the magic on the provider side. You return values that will be used in that expression, from the provider state callback. e.g. https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/examples/v3/provider-state-injected/provider/account-service.test.js#L36-L37

Please provide a full minimal reproducible example for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the path can be validated with Pact.

```
path: fromProviderState(
        `/data/xml/\${id}`,
        Matchers.regex(
          /^\/data\/xml\/[0-9]+$/,
          `/data/xml/${id}`
        )
      ) as Matchers.Path,
```

Change regex to what suits best for your path segment format.
It can be UUID regex, or with a specific number length, etc.